# iterate over spring:message

Tags: spring, iteration, message

is there any way to iterate over spring:message? I got some properties like  that:

```
ajax.title = foobaa
ajax.content = some content
```

and try to get a output like that:

```
{"title" : "foobaa", "content" : "some content"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring messages are stored in a Map.  You can't get the output you want without doing some work, but you can get the standard output that comes out of Map's `toString()` method:

```
{ "ajax.title":"foobaa", "ajax.content":"some content" }
```